# Windows bug check callback not called on 64 bit systems

Tags: windows, driver, bsod

We have ported our driver successfully to 64 bit systems a while ago.

But one thing is missing, which is not very important but it was a very handy debugging feature.

The callbacks registered with KeRegisterBugCheckReasonCallback is never called. The function returns a TRUE for success, but my callback is never called. I also tried different values for the parameter reason with no success. A try with the older KeRegisterBugCheckCallback also failed.

What I am doing wrong?

Did I missed something in the documentation?

Comment: Googling around seems like it should work.  ¯\(°_o)/¯  i tried.

Comment: I didn't found any sources which are specific to x64 Windows, just either 'old' once, before x64 time, or generic once. And my experience is that the callbacks are just not called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

Windows only calls the callbacks if corresponding KBUGCHECK_CALLBACK_RECORD is aligned to an 8 byte address.

For some reason mine where aligned to 4 byte addresses.

It is a bummer that KeRegisterBugCheckReasonCallback does not check this.